# Get SVN External over HTTP

Tags: c#, .net, svn

In my code, I'm using a System.Net.WebClient to get individual files from an SVN repository, and this works fine.

I have an SVN external that I want to get some files from, and therefore cannot access these files in the same manner. 
What I would like to do is find what location the external is actually pointing to and then get the files from that location directly.

Is there any way of getting the SVN external property definition in .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a .NET binding for SVN such as [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/).  Then you could access the properties in your program using something like the `SvnPropertyValue` class.

Also, in order to read the property values, I think you would have to check out the files rather than doing a direct download or export, since when you do the latter you get only the files themselves without any SVN metadata.